# to fetch and display visitors IP address working on different operating systems on our own system

Tags: php, linux

If two persons using different operating systems(say linux and windows) visiting the same site and I want to fetch IP addresses of both person's system and see it on my system then how can I do that?
I am working on PHP Codeigniter.
Can anybody suggest me any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

For Codeigniter use

```
echo $this->input->ip_address();
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I want visitors ip address and I am still getting my own local Ip address.